# Best way to parse some HTML code in Android

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

I'm currently developing a small application for my parents' restaurant. The restaurant has a webpage where the clients have a private zone where they can see the status of their account after they log in.

Let's assume I log in succesfully and now I can see that private **HTML** after login. There, i'd like to **parse some data**.

My question is, I think, quite simple. I know I can use **JSOUP** for this task but I can also manage to do it by using **Strings and Substrings**.

**Which method is best and why?** I've looking for a while and I can't decide which to use.

Thanks in advance,

Alex

Comment: Why not JSoup? It is very easy to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jsoup is a better method, it is a library built for html parsing.

Using strings and substrings can be very error prone and lead you to writing a lot of code for something an html parsing library can already do easily.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll try to learn the basics!